# observeSingleEvent has a delay presenting data it is getting from the firebase on the screen. Is there anyway to fix this?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

observeSingleEvent has a delay presenting and extracting data from the firebase. Is there a way to fix this? I am using this function to update the text of a label.

```
func getthename() {
    var n : String = ""
    var ln : String = ""
    let ud = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.ref.child("Users").child(ud!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {[weak self] (snapshot) in

        if let getData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            n  = (getData["Name"] as? String)!
            ln = (getData["lastName"] as? String)!
            self?.name.text = "\(n) \(ln)"
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: How did you find out it is slow? One way to reduce time would be to create section in firebase if your `Users` table is huge. Meaning, you can catergorise your Users-> (Daily Users, Montly Users, Anonymous User) and now query these sub sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data has to be loaded from the Firebase server, which takes an amount of time that is based on:

- the amount of data that you're loading
- the bandwidth of the connection you are on
- the latency - the time it takes to send any data between your client and the Firebase servers

Of these three, the amount of data you're loading is usually easiest to control, and often the largest contributing factor to the performance when you're showing an entire list of data. A simple example: if you're showing a list of user names, it's going to be faster if you have to only load the user **names** from the database, instead of loading entire user profiles. So to speed that scenario up, you might want to store `/usernames` in addition to `/users`.

The bandwidth and latency are dependent on your connection. So the only way to improve this is to get a bigger or faster connection.

The first time a client connects to the database server it needs to establish this connection. This can take quite some time, and only depends on your bandwidth and latency.

None of these can be controlled through a Firebase API. There's no magic "make this faster" API, since that would imply we first went out of our way to make it slower.

If you want to get an idea of what the Firebase client is doing, you can [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#setloggingenabled_) and study the debug output.